# Add controls to listview in code c++?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

What I am looking for is a way to add controls to a listview dynamically using c++.
In particular adding a textbox to the listview, so that I can display different pieces of data. I am creating a windows store app using c++ with xaml.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh943062?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-3).

Comment: Ah thankyou, that has helped me! +1